# Flink: how to store state and use in another stream?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a use-case for Flink where I need to read information from a file, store each line, and then use this state to filter another stream.

I have all of this working right now with the `connect` operator and a `RichCoFlatMapFunction`, but it feels overly complicated. Also, I'm concerned that `flatMap2` could begin executing before all of the state is loaded from the file:

```
fileStream
    .connect(partRecordStream.keyBy((KeySelector<PartRecord, String>) partRecord -> partRecord.getPartId()))
    .keyBy((KeySelector<String, String>) partId -> partId, (KeySelector<PartRecord, String>) partRecord -> partRecord.getPartId())
    .flatMap(new RichCoFlatMapFunction<String, PartRecord, PartRecord>() {
        private transient ValueState<String> storedPartId;
        @Override
        public void flatMap1(String partId, Collector<PartRecord> out) throws Exception {
            // store state
            storedPartId.update(partId);
        }

        @Override
        public void flatMap2(PartRecord record, Collector<PartRecord> out) throws Exception {
            if (record.getPartId().equals(storedPartId.value())) {
                out.collect(record);
            } else {
                // do nothing
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
            ValueStateDescriptor<String> descriptor =
                    new ValueStateDescriptor<>(
                            "partId", // the state name
                            TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<String>() {}),
                            null);
            storedPartId = getRuntimeContext().getState(descriptor);
        }
    });
```

Is there a better way (as of Flink 1.1.3) to accomplish this pattern of loading state, then using it in subsequent streams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your concerns about the `CoFlatMapFunction` are correct. The order in which `flatMap1` and `flatMap2` are called cannot be controlled and depend on the order in which data arrives. So, `flatMap2` might be called before all data has been read by `flatMap1`.

The only way in Flink 1.1.3 to read all data before starting to process a stream is to consume the data in the `open()` method of a `RichFlatMapFunction`, i.e., you have to manually read and parse the file.

This is basically a broadcast join strategy, i.e., each parallel instance of the operator will do this. The drawback is that the data of the file will be replicated. The benefit is that you do not have to shuffle the "main" stream (no need to use `keyBy()`).

Comment: Ah I see. So I can parse the file within the `open()` method, but as long as I don't use `keyBy()` upstream, there will only be one instance of the operator. Will this effectively be a serial operation, though, correct?

Comment: The `FlatMap` operator can also run in parallel without calling `keyBy()`. You only have to specify the parallelism of the operator. However, the data will be randomly distributed across the parallel thread. `keyBy` would hash partition the data. If you have multiple `FlatMap` operators, each operator reads the file and holds the state. So you have redundant IO and memory usage but the operator will run in parallel.

Comment: @FabianHueske Going by this approach, every time the file is updated, the job need to be restarted to get the updated content. Is there a way in flink where the main stream records are not processed till the state from file is available. Basically can we set the processing order of elements.